# MVC Model Binder - Get individual Form Error

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Im using .net 4.5, MVC 4 and im using a model binder for a form. I have a HTML Validation summary which will display the errors as a list, which works fine.

What I want to do is get if a single Model Property has triggered an error based on the ModelState and if so, give it an "Error" CSS class which will turn it red. please see below.

```
<div class="controls">
@{
    // does this element have an error??
    if (Model.LastName == error)
    {
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { type = "text", id = "LastName", name = "LastName", value = Model.LastName, @class = "Error" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { type = "text", id = "LastName", name = "LastName", value = Model.LastName, })
    }
}
}
```

Validation Summary

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.Error != null && ViewBag.Error == true)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <h3>Error</h3>
            <p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
            <p>@Html.ValidationSummary(false)</p>                
        </div>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.Error != null && ViewBag.Error == false)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <h3 style="color:green;">Details Updated Successfully Received</h3>
            <p style="color:green;">@ViewBag.Message</p>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class UpdateDetailsModel
{
    public VIPSessionObject VIPSessionObject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Phone Number")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Motorpoint VIP Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password, ErrorMessage = "The Passwords must match")]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int VehiclesInHousehold { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the number of cars in your household")]
    public int NoOfVehicles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, null, new { @class = "error" })
```

Then simply style your .error CSS class with red text, if the Last Name does not meet what your Model Data Annotation specifies, it will use the error message provided in the Annotation on your Model Property.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can drop the:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Last Name")]
```

and replace your [required] with:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage ="Required Field")]
```

I have read in the past there are bugs with using the [DataType] attribute and I am googling around now to find the article.

Comment: even if its a DataType.Date ?

Comment: Even if it is a date using the [Required] attribute will force it to be required. The error message will show up if the user tries to leave it blank. You can force any field in a model to be required with just the [Required] attribute

Answer (score 0):

What about manual JavaScript(or JQuery) validation of a control? The simpliest example:

```
function CheckForm()
{
    var elementValue = document.getElementById('elementId').Value;

    if(elementValue == null || elementValue == '')
    {
       document.getElementById('elementId').className = "Error";
    }
    else 
    {
       document.getElementById('elementId').className = "";
    } 
}
```

Then you can use it in your form tag

```
<form method="POST" action="..."> 
... 
<input id="elementId" type="text" ... />
<input type="submit" onClick="CheckForm()" .../>
</form>
```

You can perform any verification.

OR

Set ErrorMessage property for Display, Required, DataType as @Robert advised.

Comment: I’m ideally looking for a MVC3/Model binder solution, there must be a way to get the errors individually. I can get a summary easily as shown in my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is but any new MVC 4 project comes with styles for validation helpers. Here they are:

```
 /* Styles for validation helpers
 -----------------------------------------------------------*/
 .field-validation-error {
   color: #f00;
 }

 .field-validation-valid {
   display: none;
 }

 .input-validation-error {
   border: 1px solid #f00;
   background-color: #fee;
 }

 .validation-summary-errors {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #f00;
 }

 .validation-summary-valid {
   display: none;
 }
```

And basically this will get you a red text when validation of a form field fails as long as you have:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)
```

next to your form field that need to be validated. Model and data validators you placed on your view model look good.

Every Form helper has an optional parameter called HtmlAttributes via which you can pass any html attributes you want to render on your page:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, null, new {@class = "Error"})
```

Notice the @ symbol which is there because class is a reserved word in C#...